# Why can only root write to a mounted (btrfs) filesystem

Tags: 16.04, btrfs

I followed [a tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/a-beginners-guide-to-btrfs) on creating a btrfs filesystem.
Filesystem was created using:

```
sudo mkfs.btrfs /dev/sdb /dev/sdc
```

Seems that the new btrfs filesystem was successfully created:

```
$ sudo btrfs filesystem show /dev/sdb 
[sudo] password for dwayne:  
Label: none  uuid: ada8b4f3-f4a8-4a9d-a078-2149f5d7fd0c     
Total devices 2 FS bytes used 896.00KiB     
devid    1 size 4.55TiB used 2.01GiB path /dev/sdb  
devid    2 size 4.55TiB used 2.01GiB path /dev/sdc
```

Mounted it using (as shown in the article)

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb /mnt
```

But I cannot write to it:

```
$ cd /mnt   
$ touch helloworld.txt  
touch: cannot touch 'helloworld.txt': Permission denied  
$ sudo touch helloworld.txt  
$ ls -al  
total 20  
drwxr-xr-x  1 root root   28 Mar  1 00:27 .  
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Feb 27 21:27 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    0 Mar  1 00:27 helloworld.txt  
$ df -h .  
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sdb        9.1T 17M  9.1T   1% /mnt
```

Why does root have permission to write, but no one else does? What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's the normal state of affairs after creating a new partition and mounting it as root. You have to grant permissions and ownerships using `chowm`, `chmod`, `setfacl`, etc. before anybody other than root can write to it.

When you mount a partition which supports POSIX permissions and ownerships, the mount point is set to be owned by whoever mounted it - usually, root (`sudo mount`). GUI mounting, which uses [udisks](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/udisks/), takes care of setting you as the owner of the mountpoint itself.

Comment: So theres no such thing as mounting a filesystem automatically at boot time by listing it in /etc/fstab 'cause one always has to go and change permissions/ownership on the mount point after the boot (and therefore the mounting) has completed?

Comment: @DwayneMoore not always - if you set the ownership once, the filesystem will remember it.